# Use a Python Module to Open Explorer on a file

Tags: python, subprocess, pywin32

I'm a python newbie, and I'm having some difficulty making a module out of some very useful code located at:  [Open explorer on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file).

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I get the following error messages:

> line 31: C:\Apps\E_drive\Python_win32Clipboard.pdf line 34: r'explorer
> /select, "C:\Apps\E_drive\Python_win32Clipboard.pdf"' Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "P:\Data\VB\Python_MarcsPrgs\Python_ItWorks\Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_File.py",
> line 42, in 
> Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil(filepath)       File "P:\Data\VB\Python_MarcsPrgs\Python_ItWorks\Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_File.py",
> line 35, in Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil
> subprocess.Popen(Popen_arg)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in **init**
> errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
> startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

here's my module:

```
"""
Open Win Explorer and Select File
# "C:\Apps\E_drive\Python_win32Clipboard.pdf"
"""
import sys
import os, subprocess, pdb

def fn_get_txt_sysarg():
    "Harvest a single (the only) command line argument"
    # pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        arg_from_cmdline = sys.argv[1]
        arg_from_cmdline = str(arg_from_cmdline)
        
    except:
        this_scriptz_FULLName = sys.argv[0]
        
        ErrorMsg = "Message from fn_get_txt_sysarg() in Script (" + this_scriptz_FULLName + '):\n' \
        + "\tThe Script did not receive a command line argument (arg_from_cmdline)"
        
    returnval = arg_from_cmdline

    return returnval


def Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil(filepathe):
    # harvested from... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file
    #import subprocess 
    #subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"') 
    f = str(filepathe)
    print "line 31: " + f
    Popen_arg = "r'explorer /select, " + '"' + f + '"' + "'"
    Popen_arg = str(Popen_arg)
    print "line 34: " + Popen_arg
    subprocess.Popen(Popen_arg)


if __name__ == '__main__': 

    filepath = fn_get_txt_sysarg()
    
    Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil(filepath)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is with the initialisation of `Popen_arg`. Notice from the output that the value of `Popen_arg` is:

```
r'explorer /select, "C:\Apps\E_drive\Python_win32Clipboard.pdf"'
```

This is actually a python [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). You want Popen_arg to have the value which this string literal represents, not this string literal itself. I think if you change it to

```
Popen_arg = r'explorer /select, "' + f + '"'
```

it will work better. Note also that the line:

```
Popen_arg = str(Popen_arg)
```

has no effect and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code and ran it on my machine and found two errors.  The [answer srgerg provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220759/use-a-python-module-to-open-explorer-on-a-file/8220999#8220999) addresses one of these errors.  The other is that Python triggers an error in fn_get_txt_sysarg() when there is no argument specified on the command line.  Below is some sample code, with the errors fixed and some other clean ups:

```
"""
Open Win Explorer and Select File
"""
import sys
import subprocess

def fn_get_txt_sysarg():
    """Harvest a single (the only expected) command line argument"""
    try:
        return sys.argv[1]    # str() would be redundant here
    except:
        ErrorMsg = 'Message from fn_get_txt_sysarg() in Script (' + sys.argv[0] + '):\n' + '\tThe Script did not receive a command line argument'
        sys.exit(ErrorMsg)

def Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil(filepath):
    # harvested from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file
    Popen_arg = 'explorer /select,"' + filepath + "'"    # str() is redundant here also
    subprocess.Popen(Popen_arg)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    filepath = fn_get_txt_sysarg()
    Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Fil(filepath)
```

Comment: I think you've missed the "/select," argument to explorer when you initialise `Popen_arg`.

Comment: Also the path in the explorer command line really should be surrounded in quotes, in case it contains white space characters. So the initialisation of Popen_arg should be `Popen_arg = "explorer /select, \"" + f + "\""`

Comment: @sgerg: The /select option caused an error on my machine, so I left it out.  As for the white space, I guess you have a point; will edit.

Comment: @sgerg: The problem with /select was figured out and the option was put back in with other edits.

Comment: Dear GreenMatt and srgerg:  

Thank you both for solving this problem for me.  I am embarrassed to say that I had been spinning my wheels for most of the day. and was very frustrated.  I'll go to bed happy & hopeful tonight, instead of defeated and miserable.

Since I think your answers were great and they answered my question,  isn't there some method (other than this comment field) that I should use to indicate that?