# SWT: How to open Explorer with selecting a file?

Tags: java, swt

I'm searching how to do the same as [Open explorer on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file) from SWT. Now i'm using `Program.launch(someDirectoryPath);`, but it opens Explorer within some directory, but select no file. Is possible in SWT open directory and select file in Explorer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass some arguments when invoking the Explorer executable: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457

Example:

```
Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestApp.exe
```

Comment: I don't want to open FileDialog. I need to open Windows Explorer with selection set on some file. Something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file

Comment: @marioosh I've updated my answer, but what does this have to do with Java or SWT?

Comment: I need open Explorer **FROM** SWT. For example: `org.eclipse.swt.program.Program.launch("c:\\");` in Windows environment opens Explorer in `C:\` directory. I need the same but with opening Explorer in some directory and file selected.

Comment: I did it. Thanks for that hint! `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select,C:\\someFile.txt");`

Comment: I'm not sure if SWT will have a way to do that, but standard SDK provides a way:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"explorer.exe","/select,C:\\TestDir\\TestApp.exe"});`

EDIT: Ah, you've figured it out ;)