# How to have Windows Explorer return the path of a file as a string in Python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, subprocess, windows-explorer

**Background**

I am working on a basic text editor, and need to use Windows Explorer to get the path of a file. This is my code currently, but it simply opens the file - I need it to return the path as a string:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select, "C:\"')
```

**Question(s)**

1. How would I have it return the path as a string?
2. How would I use the path to access a specific file? For instance, if I wanted to open file `myFile`, but it wasn't in the same folder as my program, how would I have it access that file, in a different folder? Sorry for the ambiguity!

**Tech Specs**

OS: Windows 7 
Language: Python 2.7.3

Comment: Do you want to display a window for the user to select a file? If so look at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/39327/file-dialog-window-save-dialog-window

Comment: @PreetSangha Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't need that. I am using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file/281911#281911) for that (it is essentially the code that I posted here.) I need the script to not open the file, but to return the path, and then despawn. Sorry if there was ambiguity.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx I'm not sure what you're trying to do for your bonus, and your original question is *slightly* vague too, but would `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:\\')` work for what you want? It looks like the native dialog mostly everything else uses (e.g. the same as when I CTRL+S in Chrome).

Comment: @Nathan that was really helpful! How would I specify a specific file type? For instance, if I make my files save as `.myTXT` how would I make it so that `Windows Explorer` could only open files of that type?

Comment: @Nathan can you post that as an answer, so that I can give you the rep? It was really helpful :)

Comment: Use a file picker dialog for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using Windows Explorer for this purpose, you might want to look at Tkinter. This is very close to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-simple-gui).

The main reason for using a third party library is that python runs on multiple platforms. Choosing a file on OSX and Windows 7 and Ubuntu is of course pretty different. This is the main reason why it is not part of the python runtime.

Comment: `Tkinter` is in stdlib that works on Windows, OSX, Ubuntu. It should be available by default if `python` is installed in a GUI environment. Though if OP wants a "native" look then something like PySide could be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

About question 2, to open a file located in the process working directory, you could use:

```
file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
```

To open a file which is in a different directory, you can use:

```
directory = 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\example.txt'
file = open(directory, 'r')
```

That would also work, opening the file at the directory specified. If there is no such file in the directory, you would get the following error:

```
 File "filename.py", line #, in <module>
   file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.txt'
```

Comment: Relative file paths are not relative to the directory containing the source file. They are relative to the process working directory. Not necessarily the same thing at all.

Comment: So, does this mean `file = open('filename.txt', 'r')` could work even if `filename.txt` was located in a different directory than the source file?

Comment: Yes, relative paths are relative to working directory

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the information. I'll look into it. I also updated my answer.