# open file from windows in google or internet explore in python

Tags: python-3.x

**strong text** I want to open the file in web browser in different platforms, I did for #Mac and #linux,  but  my problem is I do not know for windows.
Here my code:

```
f = open(orginal_filename, "r")
if os.name == "darwin": #Mac
       sp.Popen(["open", orginal_filename]) 
elif  os.name=='posix': #linux
       sp.Popen(["firefox", orginal_filename])
elif  os.name=="nt":     #win
       sp.Popen(["?????", orginal_filename])
```

Comment: checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file

Comment: In windows it is not working because the folder which contains executable is not in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: it did not solve my problem, it just open the current folder of my code based on following code:import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')