# Open a windows explorer of particular location

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been struggling to find out opening of windows explorer with particular folder location in documentation. I have tried:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,mypath')
```

All suggestions are welcome!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open explorer on a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file)

Comment: You should accept one answer.

Answer (score 6):

To open specific folder in explorer:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('explorer "D:\your_path"')
```

To open explorer with specific folder selected

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"D:\your_path"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the actual path to the `subprocess.Popen` function call. Use this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')
```

Answer (score 0):

To open explorer of particular location use:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('explorer "C:\path\to\folder"')
```