# Can't Open file in explorer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

i have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and tried the code independently and it worked...but inserting the code in my QTreeView app...it opens up the explorer user libraries with 'My Documents' in focus

i use `subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"file_path"')`

here is my code

```
def on_clicked(self, index):
    # self.path = self.fileSystemModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
    self.path = self.fileSystemModel.filePath(index)
    print(self.path

def tabMenu(self, positon):
    self.tmenu = QMenu()

    self.open = self.tmenu.addAction('Open')
    self.open_file_location = self.tmenu.addAction('Open File Location')

    self.tmenu.addActions([self.open, self.open_file_location])
    action = self.tmenu.exec_(self.temp_treeView.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    if action == self.open:
        os.startfile(self.path, 'open')
    elif action == self.open_file_location:
        print(self.path)
        subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,' + self.path)
```

Comment: @eyllanesc no error  from cmd

Comment: @eyllanesc Tried it...no changes

Comment: @eyllanesc yes..i added a print() to be sure...it's a full path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171911/discussion-between-x-black-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @eyllanesc output = `explorer /select,"C:/Users/Black Laptop/Videos/two mad boys.mp4"`

Comment: @eyllanesc found something... running the process alone gave the output = explorer /select,"C:\Users\Black Laptop\Videos\tom and jerry.mp4" while in the TreeView app self.path returns `explorer /select,"C:/Users/Black Laptop/Videos/two mad boys.mp4"` ...different slashes...is there anyway i can convert the `/`..?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes...the `explorer /select,"C:\Users\Black Laptop\Videos\tom and jerry.mp4"` worked but `explorer /select,"C:/Users/Black Laptop/Videos/two mad boys.mp4"` don't

Comment: @eyllanesc using `subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"{}"'.format(path).replace("/", "\\"))` opens the file...so i used `subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,'+"{}".format(path).replace('/', '\\'))` ...and got it to work...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.path = self.fileSystemModel.filePath(index)` returns file path with `/` which cannot be accessed by the `subprocess.Popopen(r'explorer /select,"path")`..you need to convert the`/` to `\` to make it work...converted the string by `subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,'+"{}".format(path).replace('/', '\\'))`