# Why does opening an explorer window and selecting a file through Python's subprocess return error code 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, windows-explorer, error-code

I'm writing some code that will open an explorer window and select the file in Windows for a given file path.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file), which on the face of it seems to work. It opens Windows Explorer and highlights the file as desired. However, I get an error code of 1 returned. 
Ideally, I'd like to know if the action was successful, by checking the return code, but I'm getting 1 even when it appears to be behaving correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
a_file = r"C:\a_path\to\afile.file"
cmd_args = ['explorer', '/select,', a_file]
p = subprocess.call(cmd_args)
print(p)
```

Which returns:

> 1

I have also tried using `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen` just in case that made a difference (which it didn't).
I'm using Python 2.7, and testing on Windows 10 64bit though I would prefer my solution to be compatible with as many Windows and Python setups as possible.

If anyone knows why or how to avoid getting this, that would be amazing! Thanks

Comment: On my environment even 'explorer' invocation with no arguments returns 1 every time. Explorer seems not to indicate success or failure with exit codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have been observing Windows GUIs to return exit code 1 [for a while](https://forums.novell.com/showthread.php/380358-Exit-code-1-during-launch-of-explorer-exe), and come to [accepting it](https://superuser.com/questions/1123614/what-does-exit-status-1-0x1-mean-for-a-windows-gui-program).

You might want to try to control your windows program through `win32com`, code snippet for explorer.exe [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/528893-pathcatcher-windows-utility-for-right-click-captur) and comments [here](https://win32com.goermezer.de/microsoft/windows/pathcapture-context-menu-entry-to-copy-a-file-path-to-the-windows-clipboard.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response and links, I've marked it as the answer, though I think in my particular case it's probably more effort than its worth, and we don't currently ship with pywin32. but I appreciate your time and the clarification!