# Python file explorer in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, subprocess

I just want to get a way to open and close any particular folder through python code in windows 7 and above, Any Suggestion will be a great help. Thank you.

this is to open the directory

```
task = subprocess.Popen('explorer "C:\\', shell=True)
p = task.pid
```

this is to close through the PID

```
os.popen('TASKKILL /PID ' + str(p) + ' /F')
```

The problem is with the closing code it gives me and error:

```
ERROR:The proces "i.e 12086" not found.
```

Comment: search for glob. it allows you to iterate over files in a folder, then you can use the standard open function.

Comment: But how can I close a particular folder.

Comment: what do you mean by open and close? pop an explorer and close it?

Comment: here is  a simple python code f = open(filename)
try:
    # My Code
finally:
    f.close(). The file is then closed. The folder will be also closed once you leave that loop through glob.

Comment: @MEdwin,
well yeah to open a particular file your code will work but I am talking about folders

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are quite there.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file

Comment: The folder are closed once you leave that loop through glob. You dont need any command to close folders.

Comment: @jfowkes Yes, I have seen it but it's unable to solve my explorer closing problem specifically for windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to pattern for accessing a file is as follows:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    # do stuff with file
```

This uses `python` context management to auto-close the file.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281911/10553976) see how to open a file explorer from the windows command line:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')
```

http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm

To kill the process you do:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /pid <ProcessID>")
```

Comment: I know how to open but tell me the way to close it particularly for windows 7, thank you.

Comment: @MohammadShahriryarAhmed `taskkill` is supported in windows 7 what didn't work?

Comment: @CharlesLandau I have tried this:
os.popen('TASKKILL /PID ' + str(self.p) + ' /F')
but ufortunately it gives an error of
ERROR: The process "PID" not found (PID is some random process)

Comment: That's not `windows 7` that's you feeding `taskkill` the wrong `PID` @MohammadShahriryarAhmed

Comment: @MohammadShahriryarAhmed Yeah, my bad, don't kill the explorer, you'll loose access to your system.

Comment: There's a "delete system32" joke in here somewhere @t.m.adam

Comment: @CharlesLandau Ha!

Comment: @CharlesLandau Would you please have a look at the edited Question, Thank you.