# How to open File Explorer via python

Tags: python, auto-generate

Alright. I play the game [FRHD](https://freeriderhd.com). I and a friend have a picture-to-track script. Right now, in order to select a file, I have to edit the actual script and type in my file name. I know that I can use an input to get the filename through the CLI, but I want to know if there is a way to open the File Explorer and select a certain file type there. Right now I am using this code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)
```

What I want to know is if there is any way to only show .jpg files. Thanks, and as always, any help is greatly appreciated!

- ThePurpleBuccaneer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open explorer on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')
```

Comment: This seems to be a direct copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281911/2745495). If there's already an answer in other posts, consider [flagging the quesiton as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead.