# With Rust, Open Explorer on a File

Tags: windows, macos, rust

If one wanted to show a file in a File Explorer or use the similar "Reveal in Finder" feature found on OSX, how could you do that in rust? Is there a crate that could help?

```rust
fn main(){
   reveal_file("tmp/my_file.jpg")
   //would bring up the file in a File Explorer Window
}
```

I'm looking for something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281888/open-explorer-on-a-file) python solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) to open the finder process.

### macOS

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main( ) {
    println!( "Opening" );
    Command::new( "open" )
        .arg( "." ) // <- Specify the directory you'd like to open.
        .spawn( )
        .unwrap( );
}
```

### Windows

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main( ) {
    println!( "Opening" );
    Command::new( "explorer" )
        .arg( "." ) // <- Specify the directory you'd like to open.
        .spawn( )
        .unwrap( );
}
```

EDIT:

As per @hellow's comment.

### Linux

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main( ) {
    println!( "Opening" );
    Command::new( "xdg-open" )
        .arg( "." ) // <- Specify the directory you'd like to open.
        .spawn( )
        .unwrap( );
}
```

Comment: I believe the link you provided is broken

Comment: @ANimator120 fixed. I also added how to do it on `Windows` (which after re-reading your question I think is what you wanted)

Comment: On Linux you can use `xdg-open`

Comment: I guess there's not a cross platform way to do this though?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
open = "3"
```

…and open something using…

```rust
open::that(".");
```